# Get range function in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I need to write a function to get dynamic range from some different sheets
actually instead of repeating below codes in each macro:

```
LastRow = Sheetname.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set UserRange = Sheetname.Cells.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
```

I like to have function like below:

```
Function GetRange(ByVal sht As Worksheet, rng As Range)

    'do things ...

End Function
```

But I dont know how to pass a range to the function.

Comment: You have passed a range to a function in the above. Or rather, you have put one in the signature Then call with  GetRange(sht,rng) where rng is your range variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to return a Range object using dynamic end row determination you will need to specify the function return as Range object and pass a start row variable and column number to use, in addition to using a last row method.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = GetRange(ws, 1, 1)
    Debug.Print rng.Address
End Sub

Public Function GetRange(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal startRow As Long, ByVal columnNumber As Long) As Range
    With ws
        Set GetRange = Range(.Cells(startRow, columnNumber), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row, columnNumber))
    End With
End Function
```

---

You probably want some error handling/test that the determined end row is not less than the `startRow` e.g. with `lastRow` as 3 and `startRow` = 4

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = GetRange(ws, 4, 1)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rng.Address
End Sub

Public Function GetRange(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal startRow As Long, ByVal columnNumber As Long) As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
        If Not lastRow < startRow Then
            Set GetRange = .Range(.Cells(startRow, columnNumber), .Cells(lastRow, columnNumber))
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: that's very cool and work properly, tank you. just one more question; if we need a range with more than one column e.g: A1:B25 then how could do it with this function?

Comment: i just modified your code as below and its work for a range with  more than one colu,n:

Answer (score 0):

just modified your code as below and its work:

```
Public Function GetRange(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal StartRow As Long, ByVal FColumnNumber As Long, Optional ByVal LColumnNumber As Long) As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
        If Not LastRow < StartRow Then
            If LColumnNumber Then
                Set GetRange = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, FColumnNumber), .Cells(LastRow, LColumnNumber))
            Else
                Set GetRange = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, FColumnNumber), .Cells(LastRow, FColumnNumber))
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Function
```